Counting roots of several polynomials modulo a prime
Let $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a $k$-tuple of polynomials in one variable with integer coefficients. For a prime $p$, let $r_i(p)$ denote the number of roots of (the reduction modulo $p$ of) $f_i$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. I'm interested in the possible $k$-tuples $(r_i(p))_{i=1}^k$ that appear for infinitely many primes. Is it possible to obtain an explicit description of these $k$-tuples?
(It seems that this should be an application of Chebotarev's density theorem, but I know too little of the relevant theory.)

If $f$ is a single polynomial, let $K$ be its splitting field, $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ a prime which does not ramify in $K$, and $\mathfrak{p}\mid p$ one of its prime divisors. Then $K_\mathfrak{p}$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and is acted upon by the subgroup of the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ which fixes $\mathfrak{p}$. Since we assumed $K_\mathfrak{p}$ unramified, $\mathrm{Gal}(K_\mathfrak{p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is cyclic and generated by the lift of the Frobenius homomorphism in $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p)$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This gives the Frobenius element in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ associated to $\mathfrak{p}$. For a different $\mathfrak{p}'\mid p$, the resulting Frobenius element is conjugate to the above, so we get an element well-defined up to conjugacy that just depends on the integral prime $p$.
The action of the Frobenius element on the zeros $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ of $f$ in $K$ thus corresponds to how the actual Frobenius homomorphism permutes the zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$, or any large enough algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Since the factorisation of $f$ corresponds exactly to the orbits of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p)$ acting on the zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$, we obtain the classical statement that the degrees of the irreducible factors of $f$ mod $p$ correspond to the cycle type of the Frobenius element in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})\subseteq \Sigma_n$.
Chebotarev density tells you that any cycle type that actually occurs in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is actually realized as Frobenius element for infinitely many primes $p$, for example there exists a prime such that $f$ has exactly $k$ zeros in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ contains a permutation with exactly $k$ fixed points.
Now for multiple polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ of degrees $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, you may proceed analogously: Let $K$ be a splitting field. Recording the action of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ on the zeroes of each of the $f_i$, we obtain an embedding $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \Sigma_{n_1}\times \ldots \times \Sigma_{n_k}$. For every prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is not ramified in $K$, you again get a Frobenius element, and the pattern of factorisations of $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ mod $p$ is exactly recorded by the cycle type of this element in each of the $\Sigma_{n_i}$. Again Chebotarev density tells you that every cycle type which occurs in $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is actually realized, so you only need to determine the Galois group.
For general polynomials, it is probably impossible to make a general statement that doesn't require determining a splitting field, since there might be all sorts of algebraic dependencies between the zeroes of the $f_i$.
